# Equation of Motion from Action for a Scalar Field + Matter

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, action

In a [review on quintessence](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/30/21/214003), the equations of motion (EoM) for the action
$$
S=\int\!\mathrm{d}^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{M_p^2R}{2}-\frac{g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi }{2}-V\left(\phi\right)\right)+S_m,
$$
are given by
$$
3M_P^2H^2=\dot{\phi}^2/2+V(\phi)+\rho_m
$$
and
$$
2M_p^2\dot{H}=-[\dot{\phi}^2+(1+\omega_m)\rho_m].
$$
I don't really see, how?! There has to be some assumption on $S_m$, I assume, otherwise there wouldn't be the $\omega_m$ and $\rho_m$ terms. Or could they be introduced through any general relation?

$M_p$ is the Planck mass, $R$ the Ricci scalar, $g$ the determinant of the metric tensor, $\phi$ a scalar field, $V$ its potential, $S_m$ the matter action, $H$ the Hubble parameter, and $p=\omega\rho$ the equation of state.